# While implementing stripe with angular 6 I am getting ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular6, stripe-payments

To implement stripe in my angular 6 material project, I am getting mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

For integration I am using **ngx-stripe**.

Below is my code:

**ts file:**

```
import { StripeService, Element as StripeElement, ElementsOptions } from "ngx-stripe";

constructor(private stripeService: StripeService) {
   }

elements: Element;
card: StripeElement;

this.stripeService.elements(this.elementsOptions)
    .subscribe(elements => {
      this.card = elements.create('cardNumber', {
        placeholder: '',
        style: {
          base: {
            iconColor: '#666EE8',
            color: '#31325F',
            lineHeight: '40px',
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontSize: '18px',
            '::placeholder': {
              color: '#CFD7E0'
            },
          }
        }
      })
      this.card.mount('#card-element')

      let cvc = elements.create('cardCvc', {
        placeholder: '',
        style: {
          base: {
            iconColor: '#666EE8',
            color: '#31325F',
            lineHeight: '40px',
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontSize: '18px',
            '::placeholder': {
              color: '#CFD7E0'
            },
          }
        }
      })
      cvc.mount('#card-cvc');

      let exp = elements.create('cardExpiry', {
        placeholder:'',
        style: {
          base: {
            iconColor: '#666EE8',
            color: '#31325F',
            lineHeight: '40px',
            fontWeight: 300,
            fontSize: '18px',
            '::placeholder': {
              color: '#CFD7E0'
            }
          }
        }
      })
      exp.mount('#card-exp');
    });

onSubmit() {
    const name = 'Joe'
    this.stripeService
      .createToken(this.card, { name } )
      .subscribe(obj => {
        if (obj) {
          console.log("Token is --> ", obj.token.id);

        } else {
          // Error creating the token
          console.log("Error comes ");
        }
      });
  }
```

**html file:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="example-form" *ngIf="name==='credit'">
    <div mat-dialog-content>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                  <div class="card-style-number">
                      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
                            <span id="card-element" matInput></span>
                      </mat-form-field>
                   </div>
              </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">    
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 card-style">
               <mat-form-field class="example-half-width" >
                    <span id="card-cvc" matInput></span>
               </mat-form-field>
           </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 card-style">
             <mat-form-field class="example-half-width" >
                 <span id="card-exp" matInput></span>
             </mat-form-field>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
        <div mat-dialog-actions *ngIf="name==='credit'">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                   <div class="Rectangle-3">
                      <button cdkFocusInitial class="checkout" type="submit">CHECKOUT</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin:10px 0px 10px 0px">
                 <div class="Within-tap-checkout">
                     <span>Within tap checkout it means you agree with <span style="color:#76a6ef">Terms & Conditions</span> </span>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </form>
```

As stripe elements generate input elements themselves I am not able to add **MatInput** anywhere. Please help me out..

Comment: did you import `MatInputModule` in the module file?

Comment: Yes @riazosama, I already added.

Comment: Try this `<input id="card-element" matInput>` instead of `<span id="card-element" matInput></span>`

Comment: @nitin9nair, By doing that I am getting this error: "Stripe Elements must be mounted in a DOM element that can contain child nodes. `input` elements are not permitted to have child"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here I am answering my own question so that someone can get help. By putting input tag inside the span tag and put matInput with input element.

Here is my code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="example-form">
   <div mat-dialog-content>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" >
                  <span id="card-element">
                       <input matInput=number placeholder="Card number" />
                   </span>
               </mat-form-field>
           </div>
       </div>
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <div class="example-form">
                  <mat-form-field class="example-half-width" >
                      <span id="card-exp">
                           <input matInput placeholder="Expiration date">
                      </span>
                  </mat-form-field>
                   <mat-form-field class="example-half-width" >
                       <span id="card-cvc">
                            <input matInput=number placeholder="CVV" />
                       </span>
                     </mat-form-field>                            
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div mat-dialog-content>
           <div class="row Rectangle-4-Copy">
               <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="Rectangle-3">
                     <button cdkFocusInitial class="checkout" type="submit">CHECKOUT</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin:10px 0px 10px 0px">
                  <div class="Within-tap-checkout">
                      <span>Within tap checkout it means you agree with <span style="color:#76a6ef">Terms & Conditions</span> </span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripe elements inserts its own form as an Iframe. You have no control over it for security reasons. You can't make Stripe Elements form controls to be Material Input controls, you could only use css to make it look similar.

Replace  `<span id="card-element" matInput></span>` with normal block, e.g.

`<div id="card-element></div>`.

It won't be a material input form, but at least it will work.